# Simple Probability Inequality

Tags: probability

Let $P(A)=\frac{4}{5}$ and $P(B)=\frac{1}{4}$

Show that

$\frac{1}{20}\le P(A \cap B)\le\frac{1}{4}$

So how would i show this? Would i use one of the probability conditions?

I know that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$

would this be of any use?

Some help would be much appreciated as i cannot find a similar example to this anywhere!

Many thanks

Comment: Yes, that would be of use for the lower bound. For the upper, look at the numbers.

Comment: $A\cap B\subset B$.

Comment: $A\subseteq (A\cup B)\subseteq U$.

Comment: i dont understand how it is bigger than 1/20

Answer (score 1):

$A\cap B\subset B$, so $P(A\cap B)\leq P(B) =\frac14$.
For the the lower bound, inclusion-exclusion gives you
$P(A\cap B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)\geq \frac45+\frac14-1=\frac1{20}$.

Answer (score 0):

$1 \ge P(A \cup B)  =  P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$

$ P(A \cap B) \ge P(A) + P(B) - 1$

Comment: Thanks but it must be true as it is on a practice exam paper?! No sols though.

Comment: @Bernard.Mathews sorry read your q wrong.